# A stock today price 100, tomorrow it becomes 50 or 200. There is also a casino you could bet win/loss with rate 1:1. Strategy

Tags: probability, gambling

A stock today price 100, tomorrow it becomes 50 or 200. There is also a casino you could bet win/loss with rate 1:1. What is your strategy to make money?

I denote the probability of stock rises the other day as p and betting it goes down with money x. Then the expectation of gain is
$f(p)=p(100-x)+(1-p)(-50+x)=(1-2p)x+150p-50$

When $0<p<\frac{1}{2}$,$f(p)>0$ is $x>-75-\frac{25}{2p-1}$

When $\frac{1}{2}<p<1$, I got $x<-75-\frac{25}{2p-1}$

Can’t find an arbitrary? What’s wrong?

Comment: From an expected value point of view the casino doesn't matter.  If you know $p$ you should either buy or short the stock.  Compute the expected value as a function of $p$ and compare with $100$

Comment: In the casino are you betting on whether the stock goes up or down? I assume that's the idea and then you can arbitrage the 1:1 odds against the 1:2 odds the market is implying.